# Why won't Windows 7 install my downloaded .NET 3.5 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

When I try and install SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition, it stops and says I need .NET 3.5 SP1.

Windows 7 has .NET 3.5 installed (I selected it in features) but I guess it's not SP1? (I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate RTM).

I tried installing .NET 3.5 SP1, but it just stops after I click on the .exe.

Ideas?

**Error:  .NET 3.5 installation has failed. SQLServer 2008 requires .NET Framework 3.5 to be installed.**

I have already installed Visual Studio 2008.  I have selected 3.5 in programs/features (I checked the main checkmark, there are 2 sub-checkboxes that I didn't select)

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition includes the installer for Framework 3.5 SP1 and should automatically install the Framework before launching the wizard. There is a known problem with Windows 7 and SQL Server 2008 since it requires SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1.

However [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2009/06/24/installing-net-3-5-framework-for-sql-server-2008-on-a-windows-7-windows-2008-rc2-builds.aspx) blog post as well as [this](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Make-Windows-7-Play-Nice-with-SQL-Server-2008-116126.shtml) discussed the problem at length with links to the KB articles with regards to installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7.

Comment: the first blog post suggestion (run dotnet35setup with windows vista sp1 compatibility) doesn't work either, it fails with a cryptic "setup error"

Answer (score 4):

[Windows 7 Final includes .NET 3.5 SP1](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/07/22/windows-7-is-final-and-includes-net-3-5sp1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're installing from an account that has administrator priveleges.

Also, if you're on a domain, make sure there aren't any group policy restrictions in place. I've encountered the error you're getting when attempting to install Visual Studio as a user with local admin rights, because there was a group policy restriction preventing access to the security log (which the .NET installer needed access to, for some reason).

Comment: Actually you can always right-click any EXE and select "Run as Administrator" to elevate its privileges.